# matrix representation of $f$ with respect to the union of two ordered bases for $\ker f$ and $\ker (f-id_V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can you help me with this problem?

Let $f:V\longrightarrow V$ be a linear tansformation such that $f\circ f = f$. Let $B'$ be an ordered basis for $\ker f$ and $B''$ be an ordered basis for $\ker (f-id_V)$. If B is the ordered basis for $V$ such that $B=B'\cup B''$, what is the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to $B$ and $B$ given by $m(f)_{B,B}$?

Thank you!

Comment: okay. thanks. so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Let me think it through.

Comment: okay thank you so much. please help me.

Comment: Basically, the matrix representation of a linear map  is defined by the value of f on basis vectors; the image of each basis vector becomes a column in the representing matrix.

Comment: diag($0,0,\dots,1,1,\dots$)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** How does $f$ act on the image of $(f-\text{Id}_V)?$ On the kernel of $(f-\text{Id}_V)$?

> Write $f\circ f$ as $f^2$. $$f(f-\text{Id}_V) = f^2 - f = f - f = 0.$$ So $f$ is the zero map on the image. On the other hand, if $f(v) = v$, so $v\in \text{ker}(f-\text{Id}_V)$, then $f^2(v)=f(v)=v$, so $f$ acts as the identity on $\text{ker}(f-\text{Id}_V)$. Now can you write that matrix?

Comment: thank you so much! also, how can i show that $V=\ker f \oplus \ker(f-id_V)$? how can i show that if $v\in V$, then $v=a+b$, where $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=b$. thanks.

Comment: @JeanaChiu Can you show a relation between $\ker f$ and $\text{Im}(f-\text{Id}_V)$?

Comment: Note that $\ker(f-{\rm id})={\rm im}\; f$!

Comment: @JeanaChiu Pedro's way is simpler, but they come out the same.

Comment: $v=v-f(v)+f(v)$. Observe that ${\rm im\,}f=\ker(f-{\rm Id}_V)$.

Comment: @Berci I'm sorry, is there a simple way to see $\text{Im}f = \ker (f-\text{Id}_V)$ from $v=v-f(v)+f(v)$? I'm trying to see it. My way to prove that would be more complicated.